# Automatically extend object to some inheriting class

Tags: oop, inheritance, casting

Let's suppose I've got following declarations:

```
public class ClassA
{
  public string FieldA = "Something first";
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
  public string FieldB = "Something second";
}
```

As we all know object of `ClassB` can be used in every place where `ClassA` is required. For example a method

```
public void DoSthWithObject(ClassA a);
```

can be called like this:

```
ClassB b = new ClassB();
DoSthWithObject(b);
```

It is also possible to cast inherited type as parent type:

```
ClassA a = (b as ClassA);
```

So compiler/framework know how to "use" data of `ClassB` where `ClassA` is required.

And now the question: **is it possible to somehow do the other way round?** Let's suppose I've got a variable of type `ClassA` and I want to start using it as `ClassB` but at the same time keep all fields that `ClassB` inherits from `ClassA` and do not instantiate a new object? I understand that it would require extending memory allocated for object of `ClassA` to accomodate fields of `ClassB`.

Simply speaking I want to do something like this:

```
ClassA a = new ClassA();
ClassB b = (a as ClassB); // some magic happens here
```

(I know I could implement `IConvertible` and use `Convert` or provide some cloning mechanism but I wanted to avoid such solutions.)

**EDIT**

As it seems that answers are concentrating on proposing alternative solutions or warning me about even thinking to do as I want, I decided to slightly change my question and propose a bounty so maybe I could get better answers.

First of all I want this to be language agnostic.

Second: I really **do** understand, that *not every tool is a hammer*, and I can (I hope) distinguish *Jack* from *Jane*. I also do not need a lesson on fundamental OOP (unless somebody can actually prove I am making a fundamental conceptual mistake which I am obviously not aware of at the moment). What I want to know is **if and why is an automated parent-to-subclass conversion logically impossible** and if it is possible (and as it seems from comments there are languages where it *is* possible) then **why it is dangerous/full of flaws**. It is also very interesing how is it actually techincally done in these languages, that "supports" it (or at least do not forbid it).

But I do expect real programming examples and not mere metaphors.

Just to make it clear: I am not looking for information on downcasting a previously upcasted object. This is not the case here.

If I am a guy who expects to simultaneously aggregate and group by on the same table column - show me this please. I know I am smart enought to understand. :-) I just do not want to leave this question with a feeling that there is something fundamental about OOP that I do not catch.

**NOTICE**

In comment under David's answer I was mentioning *floats* but actually referring to *real numbers* (mathematical term). It's due to my rather imperfect English. Please stop picking on it. :]

**THANK YOU**

I'd like to thank everybody for their answers. I decide to give a bounty to Steve, but it doesn't mean that I consider the question closed. I am still looking for arguments against automated object conversion. I must admin that I feel a little dissapointed that those who were warning me most could not provide clear examples related to conversion (and not related to casting).

From my own research I decided to note out a few things in a separate answer (in case somebody may find them usefull). Please feel free to edit and extend the list.

Comment: This is rather just a curiosity. But it came from a multi-layer service, where each layer needs to add some information to the object before passing this object to the underlying layer. I wanted each layer to use respective level of inheritance hierarchy (to avoid passing empty fields).

Comment: then use multiple interfaces... or composition.

Comment: Thanks, I am using composition now. I was simply wondering about different solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an implementation detail of the specific language, not an inherent limitation of object-oriented thinking.  I can imagine many scenarios where this behavior would be desirable - maybe a Shape is a Rectangle, but the we decide to change it into a Square (because a square is a type of rectangle).  As you have noted, doing this sort of thing in classical OO languages like Java or C# is painful.

Language design is all about trade-offs, and this particular feature did not make the cut in C# or Java and many other OO languages.  To see why...

Lets consider my Rectangle => Square example for a minute.  Perhaps in my new language Z##, I choose to internally store object instances as composited of the objects from which they inherit.  So my Rectangle is a Shape instance in memory, + some properties and methods.  Then a Square is just a Rectangle shape instance + some properties and methods.  Changing a Rectangle into a Square is easy then, because I don't need to transform anything - just provide the ready-made Rectangle when instantiating the Square.

Languages like C# and Java do not actually do this - they store object instances "flattened" - in C# a Square instance does **not** contain a Rectangle instance **in memory** - it just shares the **interface** of a Rectangle.  So to implement this feature in those languages is much slower, because they actually have to copy the whole flattened structure to new memory locations.

Comment: Steve, I find your answer as most closely related to my mini-research here although it is rather theoretical not practical. :] Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

No! From the fundamental description of the classes, ClassA is **not** a ClassB. The relationship you describe is not symmetric/reflexive. Think of it this way: Every hammer is a tool, but not every tool is a hammer. If you need to turn a screw, you need a tool, but a hammer won't do the job. Replace the class definitions above with that analogy, and I think it becomes fairly clear on its face why the relationship doesn't work.

Comment: +1 'Every hammer is a tool, but not every tool is a hammer' - perfect.

Comment: Dear David, every integer is float, but not every float is integer. We however sometimes need to convert both ways. :]

Comment: @KubaWyrostek There is no integer which is also a float.  The compiler just inserts conversion logic where necessary.  If you want that same effect in the relationships between your classes, then define implicit cast operator methods.

Comment: @Kuba , every integer is a float? You need to go back and unlearn some stuff.The map is not the territory

Comment: @Kuba Yyrostek - "We..need to convert." Precisely. You want the conversion to be *implicit*, where it must be *explicit*. In other words, you have to *tell* me how to use any tool as a hammer...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, I had thought I didn't need to be soooo precise about distinguishing logical and technical speaking of intergers and floats. I know these are internally different.

Comment: @DavidW, exactly. But I was wondering if (and why if not) is it possible to automatically convert parent class to denoted child class **without** defininig explicit conversion. Hammer/tool analogy is nice but does not describe possible compiler limitations. :-)

Comment: It is not possible because they are not the same things!!! You are trying to force this into a compiler limitation when it is, in reality, a conceptual impossibility. The tool/hammer analogy illustrates it. If you design an arbitrary class, and then create a subclass, and try to force the parent into the subclass, you, as the designer, have the obligation to tell the world how to *make* that conversion *because it does not exist naturally*. I'm not quite sure how else to explain it. The way around your problem is interfaces or composition, not inheritance.

Comment: David, tool/hammer analogy is, as I said, nice. But not precise, please. Classes consists of data and code. Inheriting class simply adds some new data and some new code. So why is it not possible to *automate* the process of conversion (maybe except some cases of field visibility)? I do not agree that this is *conceptual impossibility*, sorry. As long as `FieldA` exists in both `ClassA` and `ClassB` I see no problem adding space for `FieldB` in some `ClassA` object - thus creating `ClassB` object. That's how you implement conversion actually...

Comment: And what rules do you use to construct the missing data on the base class? A random number generator? Pixie dust? Make everything null? Or maybe 5,127.6? You're asking the compiler to manufacture data to create the illusion of a natural relationship that does not exist.. It's a completely false relationship.

Comment: Oh David, and what rules do you apply to initialize fields of a new object? Please stop being ironic.

Comment: @Kuba, This discussion has deteriorated from an interesting philosophical discussion about class design into the theater of the absurd, and I no longer choose to participate. "Downcasting" classes to a subclass as you suggest is a fundamentally flawed concept, as I've stated, and many others have suggested a more sound way of achieving what you're describing. You clearly don't agree, despite the considerable contrarian opinion here, and I have neither the time nor interest to rehash fundamental object design theory for you in this forum. Good luck.

Comment: @Kuba. We all have ideas that turns out to be duds. So you made a mistake, great, something to learn from. Cast does not call an initialiser, it tells the compiler that despite all evidence to the contrary the programmer knows best. Rest assured David W, me and every one else in this game has discovered, "This may not always be the case"

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, I must admin I do not understand your statements (especially the last one). :-(

Comment: @Kuba. C# strong static typing coupled with .net's common typing system is fighting what you want every step of the way. In fact one of the fundamentals of the entire language design was that this sort of manouevre would be disallowed. It caused so many run time time failures in C and C++ they said "No more". Seriously if this is the way you feel comfortable expressing yourself and there's nothing wrong with it, use a different language, C# just doesn't have the right "words"

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, thank you. So now it seems to me that it is rather a problem of *dangerousity* than *conceptual impossiblity*. If you could please elaborate a little bit on it in a separate answer, so I could accept it.

Comment: Guys, when I need to "cast" parent class to subclass I usually instatiate subclass and copy relevant data from parent to subclass. I was just wondering if it is *technically* possible to automate what I was doing. And you treat me as if I couldn't understand fundamental concepts of OOP.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson are you aware of languages that allow such construct?

Comment: Ruby's mixin might be the closest, if you squint. Bear in mind downcasting is a recognised operation in .net, but not in C#.

Comment: Only solution with inheritance in C# is an explicit cast, that's why we've been butting heads. It needs no elaboration and I refuse to put that as an answer with my name against it, it's not answer. It's a bag full of horrible problems that you haven't run into yet.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, I wasn't asking to elaborate on "explicit cast" but on "horrible problems". What I cannot understand is why you talk like "oh, we are old, experienced programmers, that went ourselves through all problems of OOP and you, newbie, either take it for granted or shut up and go play with tools until you understand they're not hammers" - instead of giving a single, convincing example. Do you want me (and everybody else here) to **believe** your statments or **understand** them? You do not want to elaborate? OK. I guees I need to wait for somebody that can explain properly.

Comment: "downcasting is a recognised operation in .net" - that is interesting. Could you please at least point me to some specification/documentation/article so I could understand how is it done and maybe understand some flaws myself? Thank you.

Comment: Why explicits casts are bad. Girl Jane = (Girl)Jack. Prepare for a surprise, because Jack is not a girl! That plain enough for you. Read up on the .net framework, particularly the CLR. And I knew Explicit casting was bad before windows was invented!

Answer (score 1):

I'm with @DavidW.
But sometimes problems with inheritence can be solved by composition.

Please read this [wikipedia artice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Another option is to use an interface.

```
public interface IProvideSomeData
{
    string Data { get; }
}

public class ClassA, IProvideSomeData
{
  public string FieldA = "Something first";

  string IProvideSomeData.Data { 
     get { return FieldA; }
  }
}

public class ClassB : ClassA, IProvideSomeData
{
  public string FieldB = "Something second";

  string IProvideSomeData.Data { 
     get { return FieldB; }
  }
}

public class ClassC : IProvideSomeData
{
  public string FieldC = "Something second";

  string IProvideSomeData.Data { 
     get { return FieldC; }
  }
}    

public void DoSthWithObject(IProvideSomeData a);
```

this way `DoSthWithObject` depends on an interface and is then much more reusable.

Answer (score 1):

I give a try to your problem in C#. I tried to do it language agnostic (no c# static extension method) with generic (but it can be changed with a Type parameter and a cast).

For a full automated system like that, a new generic class should be created and used for all class properties with the following logic: Search internal class if exists or return private if none (some introspection may be needed too).

The scenario I try to answer is the one you firstly submitted:

> ClassA a = new ClassA(); 
>   ClassB b = (a as ClassB); // some magic
>   happens here

```
using System;
namespace test
{
/// <summary>
/// Base class A
/// </summary>
public class ClassA
{
    private string prop1;

    public ClassA InternalClassA { get; set; }

    public string Prop1
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.InternalClassA == null)
            {
                return prop1;
            }
            else
            {
                return this.InternalClassA.Prop1;
            }
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.InternalClassA == null)
            {
                this.prop1 = value;
            }
            else
            {
                this.InternalClassA.Prop1 = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public T AsClass<T>() where T : ClassA
    {
        T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        obj.InternalClassA = this;
        return obj;
    }
}
}

namespace test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Child class B
    /// </summary>
    public class ClassB : ClassA
    {
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;
namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Instantiate A
            ClassA a = new ClassA();
            a.Prop1 = "foo";

            Console.WriteLine("Base a.prop1: " + a.Prop1);
            // a as ClassB
            ClassB b = a.AsClass<ClassB>();
            b.Prop2 = "bar";

            Console.WriteLine("Base b.prop1: " + b.Prop1);
            Console.WriteLine("Base b.prop2: " + b.Prop2);

            // Share memory
            b.Prop1 = "foo2";

            Console.WriteLine("Modified a.prop1: " + a.Prop1);
            Console.WriteLine("Modified b.prop1: " + b.Prop1);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Base a.prop1: foo
Base b.prop1: foo
Base b.prop2: bar
Modified a.prop1: foo2
Modified b.prop1: foo2
```

I hope it will give you some idea to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you Vince, for this excellent alternative approach. What is absolutely stunning about this idea of *self-composition* is that `B` does not need to know details of `A` to successfully "clone" (wrap) it. The only limitation I can think of is that `A` must be prepared to be "wrappable" by design (which is not a limitation as long as you remember to wrap each field this way).

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is what you're trying to achieve has little to do with inheritance.

In fact let's say you have this:

```
class A {

    int a;

    public A(int a){

        this.a = a;

    }

    public int get(){

        return a;

    }

    public String whoAmI(){

       return "I am class A";

    }

}

class B extends A {

    int b;

    public B(int a, int b){

        super(a);

        this.b = b;

    }

    public int getA(){

        return super.get();

    }

    public int getB(){

        return b;

    }

    public String whoAmI(){

       return "I am class B";

    }

}
```

So now you can do what fallows:

```
A a = new A(2); // Create a new instance of A
```

**or**

```
B b = new B(3,2); // Create a new instance of B
```

Notice that creating the new instance of B you have to also pass the parameter for creating the super A class as if you were instantiating both of them at same time. This is the meaning of inheritance, building B you're actually building a new A element plus some extended traits which are specific of B.

What you want to do is something more like:

```
A a = new A(2);
B b = new B(3,a);
```

Let's see how that B class would look like:

```
class B {

    A a;
    int b;

    public B(int b, A a){

        this.b = b;

        this.a = a;

    }

    public int getA(){

        return a.get();

    }

    public int getB(){

        return b;

    }

    public String whoAmI(){

        return "I am class B";

    }

}
```

Here you see you can acheive something like what you wanted to, but in this case B is not a child of A, it is more like a wrapper to it and A is simply a B attribute.
You could also add to B a method like:

```
public A a(){

    return a;

}
```

And then just call:

```
b.a.get(); // which would be just like calling  b.getA()
```

See this has nothing really to do with inheritance as the latter is more about "When I create a child class I am actually also creating a parent class alltogether and thus being able to use anywhere child class **as if** it was a parent" ...

**EDIT**

Ok I kinda figured out an example to show in code what @David W said in his answer:

```
class Tool {

    int age;

    int value;

    public Tool(int age, int value){

        this.age = age;
        this.value = value;

    }

    public void use(){

        this.age++;
        this.value--;

    }

}

class ScrewDriver extends Tool{

    boolean starTip;

    int tipJamming = 0;

    public ScrewDriver(int age, int value, boolean starTip){

        super(age,value);
        this.starTip = starTip;

    }

    public void screw(){

        super.use();

        this.tipJamming++;

    }

}

class Hammer extends Tool{

    int weight;

    public Hammer(int age, int value, int weight){

        super(age,value);
        this.weight = weight;

    }

    public void hammer(){

        super.use();

    }

}
```

So you have a parent class Tool and two children ScrewDriver and Hammer. If what you say could be possible then you could write this:

```
Tool screwDriver = new screwDriver(1,10,true); //simple inheritance polymorphism
// Now if you could cast Tool to Hammer you could write
((Hammer)screwDriver).hammer();
```

This means you're actually using a screw driver as an hammer, but this actually breaks all the idea behind inheritance, because if you could use any tool as each other, then what is the need in defining them different tools? you could just implement all the methods you'll need in the Tool class and using them when needed depending on the context like:

```
class Tool{

    ... attributes and constructor ...

    pulic void use(){

        this.age++;
        this.value--;

    }

    public void screw(){

        use();
        this.tipJamming++;

    }

    public void hammer(){

        use();

    }

}
```

and then

```
Tool screwDriver = new Tool(...);
Tool hammer = new Tool(...);

screwDriver.screw();
hammer.hammer();
```

Comment: Hmm... correct me if I am wrong, but it seems to me, that is is actually the other way round. In first case (inheritance) you create two distinct objects that share nothing. In second case (wrapping) if you change state of `A` then value returned by `b.getA()` will change as well, so conection is maintained (not state but connection). Is it?

Comment: It seems to me that I am looking for something "between" your two examples. So `class B extends A` and `public B(int b, A a)` but then `this.b = b; this.a = a.get();`. So it's a copy. But as `A` is no longer needed (we'v got data in `B`) I was hoping to avoid reinstantiation.

Comment: Thank you BTW, that's the kind of answer I am looking for. :]

Comment: Ok that was misleading when I wrote both A a = new A(2); and
B b = new B(3,2); here in fact you won't need to write both as if you create an instance of B you're actually create an instance of A as well and whenever you change the "little A part which lays in any B" you're changing B as well and those changes will keep as changes in B, let's say there's a setA method in B which changes parent's a attribute, then writing B.setA changes B too.

Comment: when you write A a = new A(2); B b = new B(3,a); in the ongoing code, you could write a.set(5) so setting a's a attribute to 5, but no change would be seen in b (not even in b.a), you'll have to write b.a.set(5) for the changes to affect b as well. also inheritance is about using b as if it was a, but you already have an a object to work with, so why should you use b instead?

Comment: for the reinstantiation, I think you should look at A simply as a dataType and B as a class which contains such a dataType attribute, this way you can create your A class and do whatever you want with it, then if you need to "add stuff to it" or maybe do more with it, you create a B class which works with that A object you created and performs actions on it. The problem is if you want to cast A as B you'll need to afford the plus stuff B has over A (like int b) so of course you'll be calling a constructor to make it set those plus stuff, but calling a constructor creates a new Object...

Comment: OK, I understand the first one (about two objects). It's clear. But in second case `B` holds a refernce to `A` isn't it? So every change to "original" `A` is reflected in what you obtain from `B`.

Comment: Thank you, but you demonstrate casting one child class to another child class, and not casting parent class to child class. So it's basically about *changing* data & functionality vs. *extending* data & functionality.

Comment: actually what I did was: child(screwDriver) -> parent(Tool) -> child(Hammer). This chain is no good, if you would be allowed to do so the whole idea of inheirtance would be broken... what makes this chain broken? the fact you can cast a parent to a child, because this lets you cast everything to everything (considering everything extends Object) you could make Object whale = new Whale(); ((Needle)whale).sting() which is not likely to be correct. So if you want to get such a behaviour you should build it explicitly yourself as I suggested with dataTypes.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but the fact is that you are actually *casting* those objects, so the `ScrewDriver` stays internally the same although you refer to it as `Hammer`. And I perfectly understand (contrary to what people here possibly think) why this is not working. But I do not want *casting*! I want *conversion*. I want the ScrewDriver to mutate to Hammer (by stripping `weight`, gaining `startTip` and changing `use()`). :]

Comment: Right, I see what you mean, but the point is this has nothing to do with for example (Tool)Hammer which is a cast and doesn't change the object Hammer and is permitted as inheritance polymorphism. What you want is to have a 'kernel' object which is the Tool and being able to convert it to whatever tool you'd like actually changing the extra attributes to fit the new Tool you want it to be, but keeping those basic Tool attributes as value and age. This is made simply with having a Tool object and then many wrappers with the tool as an attribute, it will be passed between them by reference!

Answer (score 0):

`ClassB` will in some cases require information for construction that `ClassA` will not provide.

To extend your example:

```
class ClassA {
  int member;
}

class ClassB : ClassA {
  int bs_special_member;
}
```

There are two ways of achiving what you want to achive that are both commonly accepted (at least as far as i know they are).

**1** Dynamic Cast. I am assuming you are aware, but if not it works only if the base type referance you have actually already refers to an object of the correct type. Eg you had done this:

```
ClassA a = new ClassB();
((dynamic_cast)a).bs_special_member;
```

I don't know if this is language agnostic but most languages i have seen have some similar implementation.

**2** Constructor.

If you have an instance of `ClassA` that is actually *only* a `ClassA` and has no idea what the value for `bs_special_member` should be then you have to provide this value when you construct `ClassB`.

I would do this like so (in c++, i think you can do the same in almost any proper oo language):

```
class ClassB : ClassA {
  int bs_special_member;
  ClassB(ClassA base) {
    member = base.member;

    // Apply default value
    bs_special_member = 456;
  }
  ClassB(ClassA base, int value_for_bs_special_member) {
    member = base.member;
    bs_special_member = value_for_bs_special_member;
  }
};
```

Which would allow you to write:

```
ClassA a;
a.member = 672;
ClassB b(a);
print(b.bs_special_member);
ClassB b2(a, 35);
print(b2.bs_special_member);
```

In most languages the first constructor will allow the conversion to happen automatically, the second is just for convienince. If you cannot allow a default value then you are doing somthing wrong.

Comment: Thank you sji. I am aware of constructor based cloning solution, but this is actually exactly: cloning. What I was looking for is whether is it possible to extend existing object without actually reinstantiating it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you would do anything like this in C++ (is that what you're using?), but the concepts you'll probably want to read about / google for to get more information are called "covariance" and "contravariance."  Lately I've been doing a lot of Scala which has a powerful (though somewhat confusing) type system that allows for somewhat more complicated type specifications, including methods parameters that accept parents of a specified type.

For example, in Scala I can define a method with a type parameter, somewhat like C++ templates, like this:

```scala
def myFunction[T <: MyClass]( a:T ):T ={
  //this method accepts an instance of any subclass of MyClass as a parameter,
  //and returns an object of the same type, whatever that type may be.
  return a
}
def myFunction[T >: MyClass]( a:T ):T ={
  //this method accepts an instance of any *parent* class of MyClass as a parameter,
  //and returns an object of the same type, whatever that type may be.
  return a
}
```

You can also specify multiple type parameters, and specify relationships between them.  For example, if I have a list of "Dog" objects, and I append a "Cat" object, I should get back a list of "Animal" objects.  In the case of a list, the return type would always be either the same type or a super type of the parameter, but scala will also allow you to specify the opposite in your own functions if required.

Of course, if the function doesn't know at compile time what specific subclass you are using, you won't in that context be able to use methods from that subclass... but as it works in scala, the client code when calling such a function can retrieve an instance of the unspecified narrow type as the return type, so can continue to use methods of the subclass after the operation performed in the function.

It can also work in situations where, for example, if you're trying to override a method that returns a list of Animals while in class Cat, you can parameterize your type in a way that will allow the subclass to return a list of type 'Cat' without violating the contract of the parent interface.  In that case the overriding subclass implementation would have access to the methods of Cat.

Comment: Thank you, that is impressive. But I understand that in Scala a `Dog` remains `Dog` and `Animal` remains `Animal`, so internal object are in no way converted, they're just casted according to language and/or contract rules?

Comment: Yeah, I mean, you can't treat an `Animal` as a `Dog` in any language (afaik) unless it actually either is a `Dog` or at least has the properties of a `Dog`.  What you could do though in Scala is say something like: `trait Dog{ val isDog=true} ; class Animal; val myAnimal = new Animal with Dog;` ...now `myAnimal` can be passed as a `Dog` and has the attributes of a `Dog`.  Traits are kinda like super classes, kinda like interfaces, but can be "mixed in" when instantiating an object too.

Answer (score 0):

The only consistent way of achieving this is by letting the inherited class have a constructor that includes the base class. If you don't do that, you end up with all sorts of potential overflow problems as the memory print of the object now differs from what was originally created.

Failing to do that would get you issues like:

```
ClassA
{
    int A;
}

ClassB : ClassA
{
    int B;
}

ClassA a1 = new ClassA();
a1.A = 1;

ClassA a2 = new ClassA();
a2.A = 2;

ClassB b = (ClassB)a;  
b.B = 3;
```

In this case you may get that issues with a2.A suddenly taking on the value of 3...

Answer (score 0):

Just a few notes on possible automated conversion flaws from my own research. Please forgive me if I am not precise or speak BS though. :]

1. If we define an atomated conversion of `A` into `B : A` as a shorthand for `create B and pass A as argument so B may copy all data from A into B` then:

   - it is either a syntcatic sugar, with a very little of no control over the actual cloning process;
   - OR (if object is to be converted in-place by extending memory allocated for `A`) it turns out to be less efficient then instantating `B`, copying data and discarding `A`.
2. If `B` has it's own constructor (either calling super constructor or not) then it is not clear whether and when `B`'s constructor should be called when cloning `B` from `A`.
3. If `B` and `A` behave differently is some scenarios, and a `C` is holding a reference to `A`, then (after `A`'s convertion to `B`) the behaviour of referenced object may alter - surprisingly to `C` which expected consistency here.
4. Some languages (such as C#) allow reintroducing inherited members. It seems that it may lead to logical inconsistencies here (`int a` in `A` is **not** `new int a` in `B`).
5. Such conversion could change object's state from external code (rather then from internal code) so it is against encapsulation.
6. Each object should be either `A` or `B` (and not somewhere between) so it turns out that a conversion should be an atomic operation. Which leads to a rule that no code should operate on `A` while it is being converted to `B`. I am not sure whether it is possible to achieve such an automated locking. (This one is similar to race conditions with incompletely constructed objects).

Automated conversion is a nice idea though for classes that are designed mainly as data wrappers (structs, ORM classes) and expose rather state-unrelated methods. But this seems to be easily achieved by reflection (in languages that support it).